# How to sort custom posts including null meta-values ​in admin columns with meta_query?

Tags: meta-query, sort, columns

**SQL REQUEST**

SELECT post.`ID`, month.`meta_value`, year.`meta_value` FROM `wp_posts` post
LEFT OUTER JOIN `wp_postmeta` month
   ON month.`post_id`= post.`ID` AND month.`meta_key`='mcv_end_month'
LEFT OUTER JOIN `wp_postmeta` year 
   ON year.`post_id`= post.`ID` AND year.`meta_key`='mcv_end_year'
WHERE post.`post_type`='work_experience'
ORDER BY (CASE WHEN year.`meta_value` IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
         (CASE WHEN month.`meta_value` IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC,
         year.`meta_value`DESC,
         month.`meta_value`DESC

**RESULT**

[image: result of the request]

```
function custom_columns_orderby( $query ) {
    $prefix = 'mcv_';
    $orderby = $query->get( 'orderby');
    $order = $query->get( 'order');
    if ( 'End date' == $orderby ) {

        $query->set('meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'end_year' => array(
                    'key' => $prefix . 'end_year',
                ),
                'end_month' => array(
                    'key' => $prefix . 'end_month',
                ),
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR',
                'end_year' => array(
                    'key' => $prefix . 'end_year',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
                ),
                'end_month' => array(
                    'key' => $prefix . 'end_month',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',

                ),
            ),                     
        ));
        $query->set('orderby',array(
                    'end_year' => $order,
                    'end_month' => $order,
                )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: And i say to myself : RTFM PHIL !!!

Comment: In fact, it's not exactly the same request. The meta_query generates 4 LEFT JOIN. but it works